# Can I set a default browser per program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, browser

Is there a way to set a default browser per program in Windows 7? For instance clicking a link in Outlook 2010 would open a page in Firefox and clicking a link in Skype would open in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. The default browser setting is part of the shell.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @kinokijuf, but a workaround would be to first create a convenient way to change default browsers with easily.  With that, one could then build a script or other mechanism to invoke specific programs after first setting the default browser as desired.  (That is, for example, a script that would set default browser to Chrome and then launch Skype.)  Of course with that approach the "wrong" browswer would be invoked if two programs stayed open at the same time.

Here is a very old blog post on setting up the changing of default browsers that may be of help:  http://jimcofer.com/personal/?p=76

Answer (score 1):

You can in a indirect way. [Browser Chooser 2](http://browserchooser2.codeplex.com) will act as your default browser asking every time which browser to use.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.